# Differences between two xml strings using php

Tags: php, arrays, xml, string, difference

I'm trying to compare and check the differences between two xml strings but my code is not detecting any changes in xml strings! 
for ex my first string contains :

```
            <Result>
                <pid>10</pid>
                <DocID>29</DocID>
                <Response>True</Response>
                <DocID>60<DocID>
                <Blvd_Name>dfdfdfdfd</Blvd_Name>
                <Alley_Name>dfd</Alley_Name>
                <Plate_Number>654654</Plate_Number>
                <Post_Code>654654654</Post_Code>
                <Phone_1>654654</Phone_1>
                <Phone_2>654654564</Phone_2>
                <Fax>2323232</Fax>
                <Website>ewewew</Website>
                <Mobile_No>23232323232</Mobile_No>
                <Information>
                    <Info>
                        <National_Code>106397854</National_Code>
                        <Start_Activity_Date>2015-12-22 00:00:00</Start_Activity_Date>
                        <End_Activity_Date>2016-01-03 00:00:00</End_Activity_Date>
                    </Info>
                </Information>
                <Service_Times>
                    <Service_Time>15:30 - 17:45</Service_Time>
                </Service_Times>
            </Result>
```

the second string is :

```
             <Result>
                <pid>10</pid>
                <DocID>29</DocID>
                <Response>True</Response>
                <DocID>60<DocID>
                <Blvd_Name>dfdfdfdfd</Blvd_Name>
                <Alley_Name>dfd</Alley_Name>
                <Plate_Number>654654</Plate_Number>
                <Post_Code>654654654</Post_Code>
                <Phone_1>11111</Phone_1>
                <Phone_2>6546111154564</Phone_2>
                <Fax>11111</Fax>
                <Website>11111</Website>
                <Mobile_No>11111</Mobile_No>
                <Information>
                    <Info>
                        <National_Code>106397854</National_Code>
                        <Start_Activity_Date>2015-12-22 8:01:50</Start_Activity_Date>
                        <End_Activity_Date>2016-01-03 11:20:10</End_Activity_Date>
                    </Info>
                </Information>
                <Service_Times>
                    <Service_Time>15:30 - 17:45</Service_Time>
                </Service_Times>
            </Result>
```

as you can see there are some differences in the values of the objects!
I've tried simplexmlload and then array_diff and jason encode and decode and comparing the jason but there was not chance to detect the differences. 
any suggestion how to accomplish that ?

my array diff code :

```
 $result = array_diff($Data1, $Data2);

        if(empty($result)){
            // the XML documents are the same
            $res = "No changes";
        } else {
            // they are different
            $res = "There are Some changes";
        }
```

Comment: checking may be done only with value or structures muct be compare too ?

Comment: @splash58 the structure is important too, for example in second string it might not contain some object .

Comment: your xml is not well-formed(have errors)

Comment: @splash58 I've update the xml string can you check plz?

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the data as raw text ane see the difference by using the following

```
<?php
$difference = xdiff_string_diff($Data1, $Data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem using simple if comparison method and it worked.

I first opened two xml files and then i copared them using method below, if i change a value/structure in second xml file it gives me "there are some changes".

```
   $file = './Result.xml';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $Data = file_get_contents($file);
        } else {
            exit('Failed to open ' . $file);
        }

        $file2 = './Result2.xml';
        if (file_exists($file2)) {
            $Data2 = file_get_contents($file2);
        } else {
            exit('Failed to open ' . $file2);
        }


        if ($Data === $Data2) {
            // the XML documents are the same
            $res = "No changes";
        } else {
            // they are different: print the reason why
            $res = "There are Some changes";

        }
```